# Python same import works for some classes and not for others - importers in the same directory

Tags: python, python-import

I need to import class x from y.py file.

I can import class x in some of my files but not in others; even thought the files to which I am doing the import are at the same path.

Example:

in class c1:

```
from path.to.y.py import x
```

in class c2:

```
from path.to.y.py import x
```

Both c1 and c2 are in the same directory but import from c1 gives me an error and the import from c2 is processed fine.

Where I try using ..import, I get this error 1:

```
from ..models import Ingredient
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

If I try the path, I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ingredient'
```

I looked up the errors and tried some solutions, for example, appending the path to the sys.path but nothing has worked. Any one has faced this problem? Or can figure out what is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: You should edit the question above with a small overview of the tree / file structure.

Comment: I just needed to move the import from top of the file to the function that I would use that class,

Comment: @ baptistemm - sorry the project is too big to do that - but it is resolved in any way. Hope it helps someone else.